# How to show loading indicator for 5 seconds when I click the submit button in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project. In that project I am trying to save user details on local

Storage. In this scenario after clicking submit button, I have to show the loader for showing

Loader I installed react-loader-spinner so someone please help me how to show loader for five

Seconds after clicking the submit button.

This is Users.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Users.css';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import UsersModal from '../../Components/UsersModal/UsersModal';
import Getusers from './Getusers/Getusers';

class Users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            isModal: false,
        }
    }

    toggleUserModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            isModal: true
        })
    }

    handleCloseModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            isModal: false
        })
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <div className='mt-3'>
                            <Button onClick={this.toggleUserModal} outline color="secondary">Create User</Button>
                            <UsersModal openModal={this.state.isModal} closeModal={this.handleCloseModal}></UsersModal>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default Users
```

This is UsersModals.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './UsersModal.css';
import {
    Button,
    Col,
    Modal,
    ModalBody,
    ModalFooter,
    ModalHeader,
    Row,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
} from 'reactstrap';

class UsersModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state= {
            users: null
        }
}

 handleChange = ({target}) => {
        const { name, value } = target;
        const newData = Object.assign({}, this.state.users, {[name]:value});
        this.setState({
            users: newData
        })
    }

handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(this.state.users))
        this.props.closeModal()
    }


render() {
        return (
            <Row>
                <Col md="6" sm="6" xs="6">

                    <Modal isOpen={this.props.openModal}
                    >
                        <ModalHeader >Create User</ModalHeader>
                        <ModalBody>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="exampleName">Name</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type='text'
                                    name='name'
                                    placeholder='Enter Your name'
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />

                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="exampleEmail">Email</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type='email'
                                    name='email'
                                    placeholder="Enter Your email"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                            </FormGroup>
                        </ModalBody>
                        <ModalFooter>
                            <Button onClick={this.props.closeModal} color="secondary">
                                Cancel
                </Button>
                            <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit" color="primary">
                                Submit
                </Button>
                        </ModalFooter>
                    </Modal>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}

export default UsersModal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you'd like to show the loader inside the modal, above the form or near it..

Put the `Loader` component from the `react-loader-spinner` library where you'd like it to show, add a `showLoader` flag to your modal component's state and render the component in condition of the flag. Do not use the library's timeout prop.

```
{this.state.showLoader && (
  <Loader props />
)}
```

On your submit handler, set the flag to `true` to toggle the loader, and use a `setTimeout` to close it.

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(this.state.users));
  this.setState({
    showLoader: true
  });
  this.closeLoaderIn5Seconds();
};

closeLoaderIn5Seconds = () => 
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.props.closeModal();
    this.setState({
      showLoader: false
    });
  }, 5000);
};
```

Depending on where you'd like to show the loader you may have to move the code..

I'd put the `isModal` flag to the child component to remove the little bug where the modal is closed after the loader..

Anyway here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dubinsky-orfyc?file=/src/user-modal.js:578-947).